# jQuery change only when it exists already in div

Tags: php, jquery

I currently have page with a `div` with an `ID` surrounding a yes and no button.  When the buttons are selected the jQuery replaces the info in the `ID` with `add_song.php` file that it calls.

I have a live `change` and live `keyup` on a drop down on the page when the artist changes it changes the artist ID in `add_song.php`.  The problem is when I am selecting yes or no, if I change the artist name it loads `add_song.php`.

How do I only allow `change` and `keyup` to change the artist when the `add_song.php` has been loading after the yes or no button click instead of it loading when the artist is changed on `change` / `keyup`.

Here is the PHP:

```
echo '<span class="edit-buttons"><input type="submit" value="yes" id="add_existing_song"></span>';
echo '<span style="padding-left:10px" class="edit-buttons"><input type="submit" value="no" id="add_new_song"></span>';
echo '<div id="display_add_new_song"></div>';
```

Sorry here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#add_new_song").live("click", function() {
      var artistid = $("#artist").val();
      $("#display_add_new_song").load("php/add_song_new.php?var1=" + artistid);
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#artist").change(function() {
      var artistid = $("#artist").val();
      $("#display_add_new_song").load("php/add_song_new.php?var1=" + artistid);
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#artist").keyup(function() {
      var artistid = $("#artist").val();
      $("#display_add_new_song").load("php/add_song_new.php?var1=" + artistid);
});
});
```

Comment: instead of describing the problem, it's better to post the code.

Comment: Just an opinion : try posting the HTML / javascript rather than describing the HTML

Comment: @frictionlesspulley. I guess he thinks your way is less challenging...

Answer (score 0):

You should move the event binding of `keyup`/`change` into the `.load` [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/). `.load` may take a second parameter which is a callback to be executed right after the content has been loaded by it, allowing you to bind events to `#artist` right after you loaded it.

Also, you can merge JavaScript to be executed after the document ready into one block, and you can combine events you want to bind to the same functionality, which will remove a little bit of duplicated code in your scripts.

Considering your code, you should change it to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_new_song").live("click", function() {
        var artistid = $("#artist").val();
        $("#display_add_new_song").load("php/add_song_new.php?var1=" + artistid, function(){
            $("#artist").on("keyup change", function() {
                var artistid = $("#artist").val();
                $("#display_add_new_song").load("php/add_song_new.php?var1=" + artistid);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So when I change #artist it automatically loads php/add_song_new.php in <div id="display_add_new_song"></div> when I don't want it to be loaded until click #add_new_song.  I want it keyup and change to work after its already been loaded into the div.  Can trigger account for that?

Comment: @mxcoop98: I've updated my answer with some more info after your comment and question editing. Check it out to see if it answers your question!