# Using TR elements through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a table filled from database using php. When creating each line (`<tr>`) i'm putting it this way :

```
<tr onclick="selectedRow();">
```

I want to use the information in the table using the selectedRow() which is a javascript function.
How can i get the elements inside the tr?

Thanks.

Comment: And what elements do you want to get? Though my first thought would be: `<tr onclick="selectedRow(this.getElementsByTagName('td'));">` to pass the `td` elements found within the clicked `tr` into the function.

Comment: Actually I want to select the row and use all the cells in it

Comment: @SanjamX. There is no such thing _"use all the cells"_ You don't use cells, what do you really need to do?

Comment: this.getElementsByTagName('td') this parameter should give me all the TDs inside the row as in an array ?

Comment: I need to take the text from cells

Comment: @FelixKling: You're the most diligent dupe finder I've seen. You should be a moderator.

Comment: @FelixKling. My policy now is closing duplicate questions only if they ask about general things, not how I can make this work. You can find for almost all of the asked questions duplicates.

Comment: @gdoron: Yeah, almost everything is a dupe. I still like to search once in a while, and vote to close.

Comment: @amnotiam. For what purpose? It's not like it will make those questions disappear... I rather save my strength for [those questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135608/173320)

Comment: @gdoron: You have your way, I have mine :) I don't see a point in having multiple answers that only vary slightly. A programmer should be able to abstract the problem and understand general solutions to his specific problem. I agree, most of the questions *are* duplicates.  That's why I always search for a duplicate. But since the community decides, it's ok for me being a bit more strict than others ;)

Comment: @amnotiam: Thank you :) But in the light of my previous comment, I better not be a moderator. 70% of the questions would probably get closed immediately :D

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, they'd probably fire you because of the loss of advertising revenue. ;)

Comment: @FelixKling. Is that just me or the more you know about a subject the more you about questions-answers about it? Lately I down-vote a lot in the jQuery-js tags... :(

Comment: @gdoron: *"For what purpose?"* Mostly just as a matter of principle.

Comment: @gdoron: It's not just you... I've seen many JavaScript questions and just keep seeing the same questions pop up over and over again. That is frustrating (at least for me). Some things also just become trivial for you, because you know (or think) it is basic knowledge. On the other hand, sometimes it is not possible for people to find a solution because they don't even know *what to look for*, even if it is simple.

Comment: @FelixKling. The site suffer from a weak moderation, a lot of my flags end up _disputed_ [Last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041463/jquery-change-only-when-it-exists-already-in-div). [The one before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11023225/601179).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr onclick="selectedRow.call(this, event);">
```

---

```
function selectedRow(event) {
    alert(this.rowIndex);
    alert(this.cells[0]);
    alert(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
}
```

---

> *"I want to select the row and use all the cells in it "*

You can loop the cells like this...

```
function selectedRow(event) {
    for (var i = 0, len = this.cells.length; i < len; i++) {
        alert(this.cells[i].textContent || this.cells[i].innerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: ummm. never thought about using `call` to set `this` is the context. nice!

Comment: Thank you , this helped me alot. I'll go find out about that .call though since I don't know what it is doing exactly

Comment: @SanjamX: The `call` method just lets you call a function and manually set the `this` value *(calling context)*. So whatever you pass as the first argument will become the value of `this` in the function you're calling. So `selectedRow.call(this, "foo")` says to call `selectedRow`, but set the current value of `this` as the `this` value of `selectedRow`, and pass `"foo"` as the first argument to `selectedRow`.

Comment: @SanjamX. You accepted the better answer. Thanks for not selecting thr first one as others do.

Comment: @SanjamX: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: that clears a lot of things. thanks again.

Comment: [An interesting thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11023816/601179), I challenge you to find a better answer then @pointy.

Comment: @gdoron: Don't think I'll be able to improve it. Unfortunately, the next adjacent sibling selector does have a long trail of bugs in different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr onclick="selectedRow(this);">

function selectedRow(row){
    // row here is the tr.
    row.getElementByTagName('input').... // selects all the <input> inside.
}
```

Comment: @amnotiam. Another? What other solution do you have? select by index...?

Comment: Very similar, but setting the calling context to the element and the event object so you get the standard handler behavior. It also passes the `event` object property in IE.

Comment: ...anyway, wanted to + you since you were a little ahead of me. :)

Comment: @amnotiam. Don't worry, I believe you have knowledge ahead of me, So I guess we're even... :)

Comment: Thanks for your help , I solved my problem using @am not i am solution

Comment: @SanjamX. I would do that as well... I always upvote his answers, and if it's my question, accept it.